# Queries with NSValueTransformer

Tags: cocoa, nsvaluetransformer

1.In my application there is a requirement to display certain value (among the 3 different values) in each row of the table column,the value to be displayed in each row can be decided by checking the values of two different model key paths.

This i tried to implement using bindings,where i used "Display pattern Value1 with one key path and custom value transformer class" and "Display pattern Value2 with other key path and same value transformer".But i am not getting desired output value from the transformer class.Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

2.In the other application there is a table view with 3 columns,where the first column displays the complete word,second column displays the prefix of that word and the third column displays the suffix of that word.

I implemented this requirement using bindings and two custom value transformer classes.One for getting the prefix of the word(prefixExtractor) and the other for getting the suffix of the word(suffixExtractor).Can anyone suggest me how can i implement this requirement using only one custom value transformer class so that it optimizes my code.

Thanks in advance.